# Table row deletion in Iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a with Table editing in iPhone. I'm using Delegate and Datasource in my project.
The problem is when we click Delete disclosure, i'm not getting Delete button.
I'm a newbie in iphone programming. So please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the methods

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}    

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You also need to make sure the tblView.editing property is set to true;

Comment: I implemented these two methods.I'm able to click Red colored Delete Button.But on click i'm not getting DELETE button at right hand side.

Thanks for your reply Criss.

Comment: you're going to have to show me some code then because this is what I implemented and I have it working. So post your code and I'll compare it to mine.

Comment: Sorry Criss,now i dont have any code with me .Tomorrow i will post my code.